# PHP: SOAP webservice client to ASP.NET webservice server

Tags: php

I was trying to connect to asp.net webservice from PHP,
I dont want to use nuSOAP
I have created SOAP client using default SoapClient()

```
$options = array('style'=>SOAP_DOCUMENT,
        'use'=>SOAP_LITERAL,
        'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_1, 
        'exceptions'=>1, 
        'trace'=>1
    );

$clnt = new SoapClient('webserviceURL?wsdl', $options);
$clnt ->__Call('method', array('param'=>'val'));
```

Now, Webservice server is not recogising my Parameter that I am passing to the webservice method.

Can Anyone help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the webservice expects document/literal wrapped calling convention then you should put method parameters inside additional array:

```
$clnt ->__Call('method', array(array('param'=>'val')));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I got the Answer

```
$params = array('param'=>'val');
$resp = $clnt->method(array('param'=>$params));
```

'method' is webservice method you want to call

Method mentioned by Furgas will also work